# Differentiate/Partition between nodes of a graph to compute centrality measures in Python

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, imdb

I am using networkx package to analyse IMDb data to compute centrality(closeness and betweenness). Problem is, the graph has two types of nodes - namely, actors and movies. I want to calculate the centrality with respect to only the actors and not the graph overall.[image: The data(it is subset of the main data]

The code -

```
T = nx.Graph()
T.add_nodes_from(demo_df.primaryName,bipartite=1)
T.add_nodes_from(demo_df.primaryTitle,bipartite=0)
T = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(demo_df,'primaryName','primaryTitle')
nx.closeness_centrality(T)
nx.betweenness_centrality(T)
```

I don't want it to calculate/display the betweenness and closeness of the movies(Wings of Desire, Dopey Dicks, Studio Stoops). I want it to be calculated only for the actors.

[image: I don't want it to calculate/display the betweenness and closeness of the movies(Wings of Desire, Dopey Dicks, Studio Stoops). I want it to be calculated only for the actors.]

Answer (score 1):

For bipartite graphs, you have the [`networkx.algorithms.bipartite.centrality`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/bipartite/centrality.html) counterpart. For instance for the `closeness_centrality` the result will be a *dictionary keyed by node with bipartite degree centrality as the value*. In the `nodes` argument specify the nodes in one bipartite node set:

```
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

part0_nodes, part1_nodes = bipartite.sets(T)
cs_partition0 = bipartite.centrality.closeness_centrality(T, part0_nodes)
```

For disconnected graphs, you may try obtaining the nodes from a given partition with:

```
partition = nx.get_node_attributes(T, 'bipartite')
part0_nodes = [node for node, p in partition.items() if p==0]
```

---

Note that the returned dictionary will still contain all nodes even though you've specified the nodes from one partition in `nodes`. So you can just keep those in just one set using `part0_nodes`. This is mentioned in the `notes` section:

> The nodes input parameter must contain all nodes in one bipartite node set,
>       but the dictionary returned contains all nodes from both bipartite node
>       sets. See :mod:`bipartite documentation <networkx.algorithms.bipartite>`
>       for further details on how bipartite graphs are handled in NetworkX.

Comment: I try that with :

    demo_df.primaryName, demo_df.primaryTitle = bipartite.sets(T)
    bipartite.centrality.closeness_centrality(T, demo_df.primaryName)

And it says "Disconnected graph: Ambiguous solution for bipartite sets."

Comment: Yes `bipartite.sets` does require for the graph to be connected if I remember correctly. Perhaps filtering nodes of one partition works @ninja

Comment: It still displays movies too, but weirdly the numbers are different -

partition = nx.get_node_attributes(T, 'bipartite')
actor1 = [node for node, p in partition.items() if p==0]
bipartite.centrality.closeness_centrality(T, actor1)

{'Bruno Ganz': 1.1428571428571428,
 'Christine McIntyre': 0.9999999999999999,
 'Curt Bois': 1.1428571428571428,
 'Dopey Dicks': 1.7142857142857142,
 'Larry Fine': 0.9999999999999999,
 'Moe Howard': 1.2,
 'Otto Sander': 1.1428571428571428,
 'Philip Van Zandt': 0.9999999999999999,
 'Shemp Howard': 0.9999999999999999....}

Comment: Yes its a bit unintuitive. It is mentioned in the docs, see update @ninja

Comment: Thanks, so is there no way to filter the nodes in the result? :/

Comment: Doesn't look like it @ninja

Comment: What you can do though, as mentioned, is`[node for node, cent in cs_partition0 .items() if node in part0_nodes]` @ninja

Comment: The "cent" iterator is actually not being used in the comprehension, then why do you mention it in "for node,cent"? I tried this approach too, it still shows the same

Comment: Sorry that was wrong. I meant `{node:cent for node, cent in cs_partition0.items() if node in part0_nodes}` @ninja